# GridView not displaying on selected index changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have two drop down lists, and changing the value in the first drop down list affects the list in the second. Once choosing a value from the second, a gridview should be populated according to the values from both drop down lists.

I am getting no errors, however my gridview is not displaying on the web browser. I am 100 percent it is an easy fix, however I cannot figure out whats not right.

Any help is very appreciated as I'am still learning C#

Selected Index Changed C#

```
 protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sener, EventArgs e)
    {
        String query = "SELECT Stock_Take.Username, Item.ItemID, Item.ItemDesc, Stock_Take_Item.BarQuantity, Stock_Take_Item.StorageQuantity, Stock_Take.StockTakeIDNew FROM Item INNER JOIN Stock_Take_Item ON Item.ItemID = Stock_Take_Item.ItemID INNER JOIN Stock_Take ON Stock_Take_Item.StockTakeIDNew = Stock_Take.StockTakeIDNew where Stock_Take.Username = @USER AND Stock_Take.StockDate = @DATE";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\;Initial Catalog=SmallBatch;Integrated Security=True;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@USER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString());
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();


    }
```

Gridview Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="itemIDAdmin" Text='<%# Eval("ItemID")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Description" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="itemDescAdmin" Text='<%# Eval("ItemDesc")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bar Quantity" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="barQuantityAdmin" Text='<%# Eval("BarQuantity")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Storage Quantity" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="storageQuantityAdmin" Text='<%# Eval("StorageQuantity")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:Gridview>
```

Comment: First, use parametarized queries. You are open to sql injection. Second your code does not provide enough info to solve. But my first guess would be that `StockDate` is wrong since it comes from the selected value of a DDL, so it could be a string to date conversion problem. Debug your code and check the values and see if they are what you think they are.

Comment: My friend bobby tables loves code like this....but your system doesn't. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I think WDWWD has it, so use parameters and the problem (and the risk of SQL injection) probably goes away. Further tip...(I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio.) Put the focus on the `GridView1.DataSource = table;` line, and press F9 (to set a breakpoint). Then press F5 (to run the application). When it hits that line, find the Debug/"Autos" window and see what's in the DataTable. Bonus tip: the SqlDataAdapter is disposable, so should be in a `using` block.

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks for the recommendations, I am just turning that query into a parameterized one. I have code in binding my dropdownlist two that I think avoids the date conversion problem: "DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr[0].ToString(), ""));"

Comment: The problem is that the conversion already happened when you bind it to the DDL. Try converting it to a DateTime and see what happens.

Comment: @VDWWD Are you suggesting i convert the index value when the selected index is changed in my second drop down list?